# Why am I getting an error with Lucene TopDocs totalHits type

Tags: java, variables, types, lucene

I had a problem running the sample code from official Lucene website for the **search** demo. There is this part of code in it:

```
TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, 5);
ScoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;
int numTotalHits = Math.toIntExact(results.totalHits);
```

And i get an error that says:

> TotalHits cannot be converted to long.

If i right something like

```
int numTotalHits = results.totalHits ;
```

i get the same error saying:

> TotalHits cannot be converted to integer.

The imports i have used are:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
```

I have loaded the four Jar files required for the program (lucene.core,common analyzers, demo, queryparser).

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: I forgot to mension Lucene version I use is 8.3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In version 8.3 [`totalHits`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/8_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TopDocs.html#totalHits) is no longer a `long`, it's now a [`TotalHits`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/8_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TotalHits.html) object.  The actual number is stored in the [`value`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/8_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TotalHits.html#value) field of that, so just use `results.totalHits.value` and it should work.